# Searching in data with shortcuts, slangs, etc. in input

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, search

I have table (14000 rows) with ID and description like this:

```
ID        Desc
1         Red Audi car
2         BMW crossroad without air condition
3         6 door yellow Mercedes
4         Green BMW with air condition
5         Black BMW without air condition
```

Users can enter input with shortcuts, with different word order, with slangs...

User enter input like this: "crossroad bmw wo ac"

I need match input with ID = 2 (BMW crossroad without air condition)

What is the best way how to create matching algorithm like this in C#?

Where I can find more about this problematic?

Comment: google [fuzzy search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching), [full text search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search).

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is very similar to **Keyword extraction** (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_extraction) for more information).

You need to do 2 step:

**Keyword extraction:** 
extract keywords of each rows.

**Classify Inputs by keywords**: Depending on how much each input depends on key words, classify it.